# Install mysql on linux

Tags: php, mysql, fedora

I am using linux Fedora 19
When I am trying to install mysql server on my system it installing mariadb and mariadb-server.

I executed folloing command on CLI

```
yum install mysql mysql-server mysql-libs mysql-server
```

Please help me here to install mysql on system.

Comment: try here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/linux-installation-rpm.html

Answer (score 2):

`MariaDB` is a [drop-in replacement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-versus-mysql-compatibility/) for `MySQL`. You wont realize it is not `MySQL`. And Fedora switched to `MariaDB` since the future of `MySQL` is uncertain ever since `Oracle` acquired it.

Comment: should I install it and rest of commands like connect insert update delete and all the other syntax are same as mysql.

Comment: Yes, there should be no problems for 99% cases. Do go through the Compatibality Giude (I posted the link in my answer) to make sure you are not using a feature of MySQL that may not work as expected in MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you want to install mysql ? 
Fedora/RHEL (and others) has decided to replace MySQL with MariaDB. That decision was made upon the believes that Oracle would move the MySQL project to a more closed development (MySQL AB the company behind MySQL was bought by Sun, which in turned later was bought by Orale)

As far as I know, the MariaDB should preserve API/ABI compatibility with MySQL (including adding some new features), so you should be able to use MariaDB as a replacement for MySQL.

Hera are some more information on the subject, 
- https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ReplaceMySQLwithMariaDB 
- http://www.itwire.com/opinion-and-analysis/open-sauce/58571-monty-has-last-laugh-as-distros-abandon-mysql

Hope that helps!